# WPF: Get single points of a Path?

Tags: wpf, geometry-path

I have a `Path` in WPF and I'd like to get the single points of this path. Is this somehow possible? 
(I used a WPF built-in PathSegment and I'd like to get the points that WPF calculated)

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 11):

`Geometry.GetFlattenedPathGeometry` returns "*a polygonal approximation of the Geometry object.*"  You can then iterate over the figures and segments of the flattened Geometry: each figure should consist of a single `PolyLineSegment`, from which you can iterate over the Points property to get the points along the path.  Thus:

```
  PathGeometry g = Path.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();

  foreach (var f in g.Figures)
    foreach (var s in f.Segments)
      if (s is PolyLineSegment)
        foreach (var pt in ((PolyLineSegment)s).Points)
          Debug.WriteLine(pt);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply and sorry for my late reply. i just checked this and unfortunately it doesn't work that fine. in my case I have a quadratic bezier segment and i get points with a x dfference of each about 30, while the difference shouldn't be more than 1 ):

Answer (score 2):

In WPF4 there is also the method `GetPointAtFractionLength`, which lets you get the coordinates of any point and its tangent vector along the length of the path ranging from 0.0 - 1.0.

Very handy to "sample" an arbitrary amount of points along a path.